Single 'through' model for multiple m2m fields
I'm trying to extend and refactor some legacy project.
I have some set of models which represent "hardware" of some assebled device. Something like :
class ComponentA(models.Model)
    brand = models.CharField()
    model = models.CharField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

class ComponentN(models.Model):
    power = models.PositiveIntegerFields()

class Configuration(models.Model):
    component_a = ForeignKey(ComponentA)
    component_b = ForeignKey(ComponentB)
    component_n...

class Device(models.Model):
    configuration = models.ForeignKey(Configuration)

The goal is to extent ComponentA...ComponentN with Many2Many field which suppose to contain some extra parts and those parts quantity it consist of. However I found it weird to have through model for each Component model. All of the Component models shoud have a quantity for further statistic/calculations.
Is there is some "clean" approach for implementation such a functionality?

So you essentially want to combine .component_a, .component_b, .component_c, etc.?

As minimum: I want to have a field to record and count additional consumables for each Component model (e.g screws, wires etc.).
As maximum: I would like to refactor code to reduce growing count of Component models if projects scales replacing it with some universal model.
In first case the problem is to count objects in M2M field as I need through model for each Component to keep quantity records.
In second case: I have lot of unique data for each Component which hard to decouple. So I need a solution to record consumables and their quantity for each Componenent instance.

The model ComponentListing allows you to add a quantity for each item of a configuration. The Configuration now can hold an arbitrarily chosen amount of Components through ComponentsListing which adds said quantity to it.
Spend some thought how you want to set up the on_delete functionality.
# models.py
class Component(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=XXX)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=XXX)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.XXX)

class ComponentListing(models.Model):
    component = models.ForeignKey(Component, on_delete=models.XXX, related_name='listings')
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    configuration = models.ForeignKey('Configuration', on_delete=models.XXX, related_name='component_listings')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.component} - {self.quantity}"
    
class Configuration(models.Model):
    # no field required

class Device(models.Model):
    configuration = models.ForeignKey(Configuration, on_delete=models.XXX)

# python manage.py shell
d = Device.objects.get(id=XXX)

for listing in d.configuration.component_listings.all():
    print(listing)
    print(listing.quantity)
    print(listing.component.model)
    print(listing.component.category.XXX)


The problem: I have not just one Component model. I have multiple models which logicaly are components: let it be ComponentA, ComponentB, ComponentN. And in this case I have to make multiple None fields in ComponentListing model to arrange relation for each of them. That is my initial problem. Sorry if I wasn't clear explaining that in head question. I've updated my code example in the topic head.
